# ROS electric on UBUNTU Netbook 10.04

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does ROS electric supports UBUNTU Netbook 10.04 edition having Intel Atom processor?

Any experience?

Thanks,
Prasad

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11144/ros-electric-on-ubuntu-netbook-10.04/) by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-09-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes Ubuntu 10.04 is in scope for Electric.  See [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html)  The netbook edition has to do with the UI.  The underlying libraries are the same.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3